# UIScrollView as the root view in a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a basic UISplitViewController where the view of the root view controller  (i.e. not the detail view) is a UIScrollView.  The problem is when I go to set the content size for the UIScrollView, I see that the frame.size.width is 768.0 at runtime, even though Interface Builder shows the width as being 320.0.

In other words, I'd like to do the following but the width is 768.0 instead of 320.0. Any thoughts.  Thanks in advance!

```
self.dayScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(dayScrollView.frame.size.width, dayScrollView.frame.size.height * 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UISplitViewController is going to resize the view controller to its own content size, which for sure in portrait mode (not sure about landscape off the top of my head) is going to be 768.0. As long as the code you put above is placed in viewWillAppear or a method called later than that, it should work just fine. You may need to elaborate more in case I missed something.

Comment: Thanks Christian! When I set the contentSize in viewWillAppear (I was doing it in viewDidLoad), the width of the Scroll View is 320.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on why this is needed, the view is created before it is added to the split view controller. So viewDidLoad will be called before it is added to the split view controller. viewWill/DidAppear, on the other hand, will get called only when it is about to appear on the screen, which is after it has been added to the split view controller.